# make <ul> fit width of <li> links

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a div with `overflow-x:scroll;` and in that div I have a list, and that list have some links. But I don't seem to be able to make my list a wide as its links. Which results in my links jumping lines.

How would I fix this?

My html

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">a long text that jumps lines</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">a line that don't jump</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.menu{
   width:400px;
   overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you say *Which results in my links jumping lines* I guess is breaking in a new line, then you can use this property to avoid that:

```
.menu ul li {
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Also to make your `ul` get the full `width` change his display property:

```
.menu ul {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/5KSaM/7/**